# Bigint column throwing numeric value out of range error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, bigint

One of my customer is facing a weird issue at database side. There is one stored which is having only one insert statement

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[COL_INSERT_LOOP_DATA](
    @LoopDataID AS bigint output,
    @LoopID AS bigint,
    @NumSegments AS int,
    @Type as char(1),
    @LoopData AS text,
    @TransmissionID as bigint,
    @SubmissionDate AS datetime
) AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO LoopData (
        LoopID,
        NumSegments,
        Type,
        LoopData,
        TransmissionID,
        SubmissionDate
    ) VALUES (
        @LoopID,
        @NumSegments,
        @Type,
        @LoopData,
        @TransmissionID,
        @SubmissionDate
    )

    SELECT @LoopDataID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

this stored procedure is throwing numeric value out of range error for last few weeks. We have found that it is happening when we mention more than 10 digits value in loopDataId column. But when we run the same insert statement explicitly as a separate query (without stored procedure), it is working.
Below is the loopData table definition -

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LoopData](
    [LoopDataID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LoopID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [TransmissionID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SubmissionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LoopData] [text] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [NumSegments] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BackupLoopDataID] [bigint] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LoopData] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [LoopDataID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_LoopData_NumSegments]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [NumSegments]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LoopData_Loop] FOREIGN KEY([LoopID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Loop] ([LoopID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LoopData_Loop]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LoopData_LoopData] FOREIGN KEY([BackupLoopDataID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LoopData] ([LoopDataID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LoopData_LoopData]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_LoopData_Transmission] FOREIGN KEY([TransmissionID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Transmission] ([TransmissionID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LoopData] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_LoopData_Transmission]
GO
```

Customer has been using the database for years without any issue. But sometimes they do partition pruning for performance improvement. For bigint column a 12 digit number should not be a problem.

Please help.

Comment: FYI, `text` has been deprecated for 16 years; you should be have been long using `MAX` lengths for `(n)varchar` data types by now.

Comment: Take the time to provide us with a [mre]. The above shows both are a `bigint`, which won't throw the error on a numerical value of 10+ characters. In fact, the error isn't even to do with `int`/`bigint` as you say it's *"numeric value out of range error"*. If you pass a value that is too large for an `int` or `bigint`, you get the error *"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."*

Comment: It doesn't sound like the error is being caused by what you think is causing it. More research is required.

Comment: Do you have an insert trigger on the table doing math on the bigint values?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: No

Comment: Show the complete error message - all of it. That is something you should ALWAYS do when trying to debug code based on an error. Does this table participate in a view?

Comment: When you say it only fails when calling the stored procedure are you actually calling the stored procedure directly in SSMS?  To me that looks like an application error.  I notice you have outputs on your proc.  I'm guessing the application is trying to put the output of the proc into a variable that isn't of the correct type.  It may even be inserting the data into the table but erroring in the application.

Test it by running the proc in SSMS with the failing parameters.  If it runs fine there you've not got an issue with your proc but with the calling application.

Comment: @Bee_Riii: Yes I will check today and update post accordingly

Comment: @SMor: will update the post with error stack trace in sometime. Thank you